# Folders are not creating with special characters in it

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, directory

I am making a custom e-commerce in laravel 5.8 the issue I am facing is that when I upload product images it creates the folder by the name of product in the public directory and place images of the product into that folder but if the name of the product is long or contains special characters laravel don't creates that folder and does not uploads any image as well here is the code I am using for uploading images.

```
if ($request->file('logo')) {
   $file = $request->file('logo');
   $logo = $file->getClientOriginalName();
   $file->move(public_path('Product Images/' . $request->name), $logo);
 }
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is those special characters? Keep in mind some characters are disallowed as folder-names by various operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

I think the concept you try is not a good idea.

1.) When you have a lot of images you shouldn't save them in one folder. It's possible that you get problems if you have too much pictures in one single folder. Normally you generate a hash of the image and save them in a folder structure for example: `891904122.jpeg` to folder `2/2/1/4/891904122.jpeg`.

Then you don't have the problem with the special chars.

For that Laravel has a great file abstraction.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Http/FileHelpers.php#48

Take a look at `hashName`.

2.) The second is that you should avoid spaces in your folder names. When you copy some folder between system you can get trouble.

3.) There are great Shop-Systems like Sylius which base on Symfony or Aimios which base on Laravel. There are a lot more. You can look how they solve problems.